# Access non-public data using Facebook Graph Api

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-authentication

I am trying to get **User data**(*/me*) & **Friends data**(*/me/friends*) using a function which fires after login through facebook. I am using **Javascript SDK**

```
//Getting logged in user data//
function users(callback) {    FB.api('/me?fields=name,first_name,username,birthday,hometown,albums,photos,location,picture.height(100).width(100),cover', function(response) {
        callback(response);

    });
}

//Getting logged in user friends data//
function pic(album_id, callback) {

    FB.api("/" + album_id + "/photos", function(response) {

        callback(response);

    });
}
```

By using this i am able to access all public data of logged in user, but **not able** to access data with **limited permission**(such as *my location & Hometown* is set to be visible to *my friends only*).

**App dashboard permissions:**
[image]

Comment: maybe you can access it using fql, sometimes the public data is returned by default and you specifically have to ask facebook for the data you want after the user is logged in and allowed you access

Comment: @pythonian29033 I am requesting for extra permission in Permission dashboard. According to facebook documentation it should return me & my friends data after authorizing my app.

Comment: These settings in the app dashboard are for login from the app center only – if you are handling login yourself you have to use the `scope` parameter! See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/#permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access fields such as hometown,location etc. for an user using the following code, which asks for an authorization when you login to your app using facebook.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
      }, {
          scope: 'user_location,user_hometown,user_photos,friends_location'
      });
```